# How to add rtmp-module to nginx in yocto?

Tags: nginx, yocto, rtmp

I m trying to add rtmp-module to nginx in my image using yocto project,
I could really use any help

Thank you

Comment: I think you'll have to write a recipe for it.

Comment: Is there a way to point me to the solution because, like should i use devtools to do it ? and how ?